# Aside elements not showing

Tags: html, css

I am trying out a guide from YouTube, but I can't get the right_aside and left_aside elements to show on my screen. I have been looking for hours now, and I can't find the problem. Did I miss something?

This is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <title>my websitebeta</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="keywords" content="">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="indexStyle.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <header id="main_header">
            <div id="second_header"></div>
        </header>
        <menu id="main_menu"></menu>
        <div id="main_wrapper">
            <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top" width="180">
                        <aside id="left_aside"></aside>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <section id="main_content"></section>
                    </td>
                    <td valign="top" width="180">
                        <aside id="right_aside"></aside>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <footer id="main_footer"></footer>
    </body>

</html>
```

This is my CSS:

```
*{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
body{
    color:#000;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background: #FFF;

}
#main_header{
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background: #F90;

}
#second_header{
    min-width:960px;
    height:60px;
    padding:20px;
    margin:0px auto 0px;

}
#main_menu{
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background: #09F;

}

#main_wrapper{
    min-width:1000px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;

}
#left_aside{
    width: 180px;
    min-height:700;
    background: #9f0;
}

#main_content{
    margin:0px 20px 0px;
    min-height:700;
}
#right_aside{
    width: 180px;
    min-height:700;
    background: #f00;
}
#main_footer{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: #09F;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Comment: you don't have any units for your min-height

Comment: Some suggestions for your question: Which browser?  What are you expecting vs. what are you seeing?

Comment: You are using tables to create the page layout I recommend you to use divs instead

Comment: Why are you using tables lol? Use `div` instead. Much easier + tables is very old technology. Tables are only useful now-days for actual tables or html emails.

Comment: @Mayo iam useing Google Chrome and i think that iam only seeing the main_header and main_menu. The right side, left side and the footer is ont showing up at all

Comment: it is a youtube guide so that's way i use it and iam still new to this html and css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've forgotten the `px` after your `min-height` in both the left and right asides.

It should look like: `min-height:700px;`

Good luck!

Comment: No problem - if I have helped please upvote the answer and click the tick to accept! :)